# Особенно(,) если ты неправ

Tags: пунктуация

***Не спорь с женщиной, особенно(,) если ты неправ.***
Тут запятую ставить не хочется.

***Не спорь с женщиной. Особенно(,) если ты неправ.***
А тут я бы поставил.

Причем если в первом случае я еще могу как-то обосновать интонацией (по аналогии с тем, что вводное в начале вставного оборота не обособляется), то желание обособить "особенно" в абсолютном начале предложения меня самого вводит в некоторый ступор.

"Особенно" можно заменить на "тем более" - понимания не добавляет.

***Есть ли хоть какое-то обоснование этой ситуации?***

ПС. Я, конечно, знаю, что это не противоречит правилам (наречия могут обособляться для "пущей выразительности" - http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=288384), но у меня тут объективно нет подобных мотивов. Вот просто хочется - и всё!

Comment: @JKlen - не ухватил мысль. если считать "если". союзом (а не частицей, в чем я, признаться, до конца не уверен), то то он легко заменется на "в случае если"... Ну и где там запятая-то нужна перед всей этой конструкцией?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, дело не в "если". В первом случае высказывание продолжено второй частью, условием (смысл предложения я понимаю так: постарайся не спорить с женщиной), а во втором случае мысль завершена - не спорь с женщиной (ни при каких условиях), здесь большая категоричность. И вдруг к ней прибавляется придаточная часть. По смыслу она скорее усиливает сказанное в предыдущем предложении, нежели является условием. И поэтому то, что было частицей, становится полновесным наречием. У меня такое ощущение от этих предложений.